# DataTables ordering data by column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to build a table on my html page where there is a link to a pdf from a certain user. I've given these pdfs this structure:

```
{
  id,
  user [object],
  dateCreated
}
```

On the html page, my table should have a column for the link to the pdf and a column for the users name. Here is the code for the creation of the table:

```
const $table = $('#table').DataTable({
 processing: true,
 serverSide: true,
 bLengthChange: false,
 bFilter: false,
 ajax: {
   url: '/api/route',
   dataSrc: response => {
     return response.data.array.map(index => {
       return [
         `<a class="show" href="/file/${ index.id }">Link</a>`,
         `${ index.user.first_name } ${ index.user.last_name }`
       ];
     });
   }
 },
 columnDefs: [
   { targets: [1], orderable: true }
 ]
});
```

To me, it seems as though my column at index 1(the user's name) should be orderable, however whenever I click the arrows to order it, nothing happens. The arrow points up, and the event of a draw occurs, but other than that no changes are reflected on the table.

Comment: Screenshot of table please.

Comment: And also check the console, there's likely to be an error in there if it's doing 'nothing', as probably in an error state.

Comment: I actually fixed this myself, the solution was to change serverside from true to false. After doing this I have been able to reorder my table.